# What exactly is Rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

In simple terms, what does Rake do? What purposes does it have? I understand it's a build tool but I'm looking a bit more detail.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFPWDzHWjEY) is really excellent for understanding rake at the most basic level.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try Martin Fowler's article on Rake for more information:

http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html

His pre-amble is:

> Rake is a build language, similar in
>   purpose to make and ant. Like make and
>   ant it's a Domain Specific Language,
>   unlike those two it's an internal DSL
>   programmed in the Ruby language. In
>   this article I introduce rake and
>   describe some interesting things that
>   came out of my use of rake to build
>   this web site: dependency models,
>   synthesized tasks, custom build
>   routines and debugging the build
>   script.

There is more information available on or linked from the project's home page as well:

http://rake.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 81):

These answers assume you know what a DSL is, or are familiar with Make or Ant. If that's not the case, here's a (perhaps grossly oversimplified answer):

[Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) is a tool you can use with [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org) projects. It allows you to use ruby code to define "tasks" that can be run in the command line.

Rake can be [downloaded and included](http://rake.rubyforge.org/#label-Installation) in ruby projects as a ruby gem.

Once installed, you define tasks in a file named "[Rakefile](http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html)" that you add to your project.

We call it a "build tool" because Rake comes with some libraries that make it easy to do tasks that are common during the build/deploy process, like [file operations](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html#FileTasks) (creating, deleting, renaming, & moving files), publishing sites via [FTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/FtpUploader.html)/[SSH](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/SshDirPublisher.html), and [running tests](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html).

For more information, here's the project documentation: http://rake.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 14):

Rake lets you execute Ruby code through a nice namespace api. An example is rake db:migrate. You can run tasks automatically before and after other tasks. That is all.

Comment: Kudos for sharing what it's used in rather than a technical answer

Answer (score 12):

[Rake](http://Rake.RubyForge.Org/) is an implementation of [dependency-based declarative programming](http://MartinFowler.Com/articles/rake.html#DependencyBasedProgramming) in the [Ruby Programming Language](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/). Basically, Rake is to Ruby what [Make](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html) is to C, with the notable difference, that Make is an external [DSL](http://MartinFowler.Com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html), while Rake is an internal DSL.